# C language - Can I use char for switch beside number in cases?

Tags: c, char, switch-statement

I want to let user input + or - or * or / but I dont know how to use them in switch so I have to make user input number to represent the arithmetic sign like 1 for + 2 for - and so on... That way I can use switch.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite the question - also supply what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may. For example

```
char c = '+';

switch( c )
{
case '+':
    puts( "Plus" );
    break;
case '-':
    puts( "Minus" ); 
    break;
default:
    puts( "Unknown operation" );
    break;
}
```

According to the C Standard (6.8.4.2 The switch statement)

> 3 **The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
>   expression** and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
>   switch statement shall have the same value after conversion. There may
>   be at most one default label in a switch statement. (Any enclosed
>   switch statement may have a default label or case constant expressions
>   with values that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing
>   switch statement.)

And character literals are integer constants.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It is strange because my internet is slow.:)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! So as long as I put the char in single quotes, it can acts as integer in switch right?

Comment: @AZINEZ yes, a character literal may be used as a case label.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very quick and dirty example:

```
char a='+';  

switch(a) 
{
    case '+' : //do plus stuff;
      break
    case '-' : //do minus stuff;
      break;
    default:  // Say illegal input or whatever;  
      break;
}
```